# How to prevent slimes from spawning in certain areas

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am building a slime farm and I am thinking of ways to stop slimes from spawning at certain areas.

Basically above each spawning level I have a 2-block high are where I do my lighting. It looks like this:

[image]

To be clear I am not standing on the roof of the spawning area.

There are a lot of spots where slimes can easily spawn, and I do not want them spawning there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Slimes can [spawn in any light level](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Slime#Spawning), so having your area well-lit will not stop them.

However, just as with other mobs, slimes require an [opaque](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Opaque) block to spawn on top of. You can stop them from spawning by lining the floor of your area with [transparent blocks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Opaque#Types_of_transparent_blocks), such as [glass](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Glass) or [slabs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Slabs).

Additionally, the three sizes of slimes require different amounts of room (i.e. non-opaque blocks like air, signs, torches, etc.) for them to spawn:

- Big Slimes: 3x3x3 block area.
- Small Slime: 3x3x2 block area.
- Tiny Slime: 1x1x2 block area (or 1x1x1 if the upper block is not opaque).

So, another solution is to simply fill in the area as much as possible.

Comment: I guess slabs or glass will work, but that is an awefull lot of recources yet again. But no other way right?

Comment: @SaifBechan You get 2 slabs for every block you use, so crafting slabs is actually more efficient than other floor materials.

Comment: OK well I guess that is true. Can I make the whole roof out of half slabs? Can I place redstone and redstone repeaters on half slabs?

Comment: @SaifBechan: You can't place redstone circuitry on slabs, but slabs can also be placed *on the underside of the ceiling*. However, the easiest solution for you may be to just lower the ceiling using dirt, cobblestone, etc. so that there is only a 1-block high area containing your redstone circuitry.

Comment: @SaiBechan: A step beyond that, use sticky pistons to lower the ceiling by one.  That is why you have a slime farm, right?

Comment: Water is another _very_ easy "block" to place which will also prevent slime spawning (but I wouldn't recommend it if you need to run redstone in the same area).